# How to pre-fill customer details using Paypal REST API?

Tags: paypal

We're using Paypal's REST API and we'd like to pre-fill the customer's data (email, name, address) on the approval's page.

There is a payer_info object that can passed to Paypal when the payment is created. But it does not allow specifying customer's details - email field is not supported and others are read-only. Also I don't see any mentions in the API docs on how to achieve this with the REST API. Do you know if it's possible and how? If it's not supported, is it known when it's gonna be supported?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when using PayPal REST API you can follow these instructions https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_prepopulate_outside and append the params as GET params on the end of the aproval_url before redirect the customer.

For example:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-77D44712W7736393M&first_name=Geovanny&last_name=Junio