# Paypal REST API how to set billing informations

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Is there any way to pre-fill billing information for non-paypal user using PHP API REST when I create a Payment?

This is where I would like to pre-fill data:

[image]

And this is my test code:

```
$payerinfo=new PayerInfo();
$payerinfo->setEmail("test@test.com")->setFirstName("MyName")->setLastName("MySurname");
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal")->setPayerInfo($payerinfo);
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)->setItemList($itemList)->setDescription($descrizione);
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")->setPayer($payer)->setTransactions(array($transaction));
$payment->create($this->getApiContext())
```

Seems that "payerInfo" is not used to fill billing information.

Comment: **Off-topic:** I think you mean prefill and not pre-compile?

Comment: @Script47 yes, I thought they were synonyms, sorry. In my language they are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pre-fill customer details using Paypal REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121454/how-to-pre-fill-customer-details-using-paypal-rest-api)